# "404 Not Found" for newly created Resources using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, rest, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a webpage with Laravel (5.8.35) / MySQL using XAMPP.
After setting up the DB and initializing it with some test data I wanted to create some resources to retreive the data (of students in my case).

The standard Laravel landing page in my case is located at *localhost/testlaravel/public*. I am trying to access the resource on *localhost/testlaravel/public/api/students* which results in a 404 | Not Found.

What could the problem be? Thank you in advance

Here are a few code snippets of hopefully all relevant files.

**routes\api.php**

```
// List students
Route::get('/students','StudentController@index');

// List single student
Route::get('/student/{id}', 'StudentController@show');
```

**App\Http\Controllers\StudentController**

```
public function index() {
    $students = Student::paginate(20);
    return StudentResource::collection($students);
}
```

**App\Http\Resources\StudentResource**

```
public function toArray($request) {
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

Edit1:

The console output for php artisan route:list is:

````
+--------+----------+------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI              | Name | Action                                         | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                |      | Closure                                        | web          |
|        | POST     | api/student      |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@store   | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/student/{id} |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@show    | api          |
|        | PUT      | api/student/{id} |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@update  | api          |
|        | DELETE   | api/student/{id} |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@destroy | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/students     |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@index   | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user         |      | Closure                                        | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | student          |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | student/{id}     |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT      | student/{id}     |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE   | student/{id}     |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | students         |      | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@index   | web          |
+--------+----------+------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+--------------+```
````

Comment: Have you checked the connection properly?

Comment: I rebooted the server several times, still the same error. Or what do you mean exactly? Thanks!

Comment: Check if XAMPP is correctly working, or if the IP is assigned correctly.

Comment: Do you have the standard `.htaccess` file in the public directory? What is the output of `php artisan route:list` in the console from the project root?

Comment: Yes, the .thtaccess file is in the public directory. I copy-pasted the list of routes at the top. @mdexp

Comment: If laravel .htaccess or nginx is set correctly you can access it in:  localhost/api/students (remove the folder app and public)

Answer (score 2):

You are saying, you want to create a webPage so i think you have to add the Route to routes/web.php file for web pages routes/api.php is for api's

if you are creating api, check if XAMPP is functioning also may be some connection issues
like your ip address

Comment: I also added the routes to routes/web.php now. The Apache-Logs show the different requests I make, but it still does not work.